# Scala Testing of Trait Applied to Implementing Sub-Classes

Tags: scala, scalatest

Given a scala trait with implementing sub-classes

```
trait Foo {
  def doesStuff() : Int
}

case class Bar() extends Foo { ... }

case class Baz() extends Foo { ... }
```

**How do the unit tests get organized in order to test the trait and then apply the tests to each of the implementations?**

I'm looking for something of the form:

```
class FooSpec(foo : Foo) extends FlatSpec {
  "A Foo" should {
    "do stuff" in {
      assert(foo.doesStuff == 42)
    }
  }
}
```

Which would then be applied to each of the implementing classes:

```
FooSpec(Bar())

FooSpec(Baz())
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this at all

Comment: @RhysBradbury Could you please elaborate or recommend a different methodology?

Comment: I would usually implement the doesStuff in further traits and implement the trait in the test, then test the functionality of the trait and then use a static instance of it at runtime

Comment: Interdependency for units is never a good idea imho

Comment: @RhysBradbury Even if `Bar` and `Baz` were implementing traits instead of classes I would still need to test their functionality.  Which means I either write 2 sets of unit tests, or do it according to the answer to my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the implementations of `Bar.doesStuff` and `Baz.doesStuff` have different behavior, having two separate tests is the appropriate solution.

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class FooSpec1 extends FlatSpec {

  "a Bar" should "do a bar thing" in {
    Bar().doesStuff() == 42
  }

  "a Baz" should "do a baz thing" in {
    Baz().doesStuff() % 2 == 0
  }

}
```

However, if they have the same behavior, you can refactor the tests with a function to avoid duplicate code. I don't believe scalatest can achieve this reuse pattern at the spec level like you're asking for.

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class FooSpec2 extends FlatSpec {

  def checkDoesStuff(foo: Foo): Boolean =
    foo.doesStuff() == 42

  "a Bar" should "do a bar thing" in {
    checkDoesStuff(Bar())
  }

  "a Baz" should "do a baz thing" in {
    checkDoesStuff(Baz())
  }

}
```

Property-based testing can do exactly what you're looking for though. Here's an example using scalacheck:

```
import org.scalacheck.{Gen, Properties}
import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll

object FooProperties extends Properties("Foo"){

  val fooGen: Gen[Foo] = Gen.pick(1, List(Bar(), Baz())).map(_.head)

  property("a Foo always does stuff") = forAll(fooGen){
    (foo: Foo) => foo.doesStuff() == 42
  }

}
```

Unlike ScalaTest specs, properties are always functions. The `forAll` function takes a generator, samples values of the generator and runs the test on all samples. Our generator will always return either an instance of `Bar` or `Baz` which means the property will cover all the cases you're looking to test. `forAll` asserts that if a single test fails the entire property fails.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the accepted answer definitely works, scalacheck runs 100 unit tests by default, and is typically used to tackle a different issue than the question is suggesting.

Perhaps this wasn't available in 2019, but I would like to contribute an answer that as of ScalaTest 3.2.9 (and perhaps earlier) is more applicable.

You can create a trait to house all the re-usable tests and then extend that into your unit tests. I will give a brief example below using the question classes. [The full example is provided at this link under "Shared tests".](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.9/org/scalatest/flatspec/AnyFlatSpec.html)

```
trait FooBehaviours { this: AnyFlatSpec =>
    /*
    the defined tests here should consider how your trait behaves in certain conditions
    */
    def emptyFoo(foo: => Foo): Unit = {
        it should "do stuff" in {
            assert(foo.doesStuff == 42)
        }
    }
    def fullFoo(foo: => Foo): Unit = {
        it should "do stuff" in {
            assert(foo.doesStuff == 420)
        }
    }
}

class FooSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with FooBehaviours {
    //these methods are defs but will be re-instantiated in the behaviour tests due to the call-by-name ": =>" parameters 
    def bar = Bar()
    def baz = Baz()
    
    behavior of "A bar"
    it should behave like emptyFoo(bar)
    it should behave like fullFoo(bar)
    
    behavior of "A baz"
    it should behave like emptyFoo(baz)
    it should behave like fullFoo(baz)
}
```

Excerpts from the link in case it doesn't work

> Sometimes you may want to run the same test code on different fixture
> objects. In other words, you may want to write tests that are "shared"
> by different fixture objects. To accomplish this in a AnyFlatSpec, you
> first place shared tests in behavior functions. These behavior
> functions will be invoked during the construction phase of any
> AnyFlatSpec that uses them, so that the tests they contain will be
> registered as tests in that AnyFlatSpec. For example, given this stack
> class:

> ...

> You may want to test the Stack class in different states:
> empty, full, with one item, with one item less than capacity, etc. You
> may find you have several tests that make sense any time the stack is
> non-empty. Thus you'd ideally want to run those same tests for three
> stack fixture objects: a full stack, a stack with a one item, and a
> stack with one item less than capacity. With shared tests, you can
> factor these tests out into a behavior function, into which you pass
> the stack fixture to use when running the tests. So in your
> AnyFlatSpec for stack, you'd invoke the behavior function three times,
> passing in each of the three stack fixtures so that the shared tests
> are run for all three fixtures. You can define a behavior function
> that encapsulates these shared tests inside the AnyFlatSpec that uses
> them. If they are shared between different AnyFlatSpecs, however, you
> could also define them in a separate trait that is mixed into each
> AnyFlatSpec that uses them.